# Parameter not picking up NULL values in SSRS report appears blank

Tags: t-sql, date, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to design report using Date parameters(needs be in UK date format)

```
Original date format: 2007-11-30 00:00:00.000

So, I am using CONVERT(Date, Start_Date, 103): 2007-11-30 in my query.

Data in Query:

Start_Date            End_Date                Type
---------------------------------------------------------------      NULL                  2016-01-23                 3 Month 
2009-08-11            2009-07-27                 3 Month  
NULL                  2015-10-13                 3 Month
NULL                  2016-02-16                 3 Month
NULL                  2015-12-28                 3 Month
```

Now while designing report I am using this dataset:

Main dataset Query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Start_Date, Target_Date, Col3
FROM  Table
WHERE        (Col1 IN (@Param1))
AND (Col2IN (@Param2)) 
AND (Start_Date IN (@Start_Date)) AND (Target_Date IN (@Target_Date))

Now, When I run this report for Start_Date = 2009-08-11  and End_Date = 2009-07-27  and Type= 3 Month I get detailed data in report. 

However, When I select Start_Date = NULL   and End_Date = 2016-02-16   and Type= 3 Month my report appears blank. I checked dataset and that too returns all values as NULL.
```

Can you please suggest/help with this issue?

Regards,
AR

Answer (score 0):

```
Start_Date = NULL
```

Will not work.You need to use

```
Start_Date IS NULL
```

or

```
ISNULL(Start_Date, 0) = 0
```

so something like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Start_Date, Target_Date, Col3
FROM [Table]
WHERE Col1 IN (@Param1)
      AND Col2 IN (@Param2)
      AND ISNULL(Start_Date, 0) IN (ISNULL(@Start_Date, 0))
      AND ISNULL(Target_Date, 0) IN (ISNULL(@Target_Date, 0));
```